# How to use JSF h:messages better?

Tags: jsf

My Objective is to use `h:messages` to convey user - error and confirmation messages. The CSS styles to show these two different messages are different, In fact I would like to use an image beside the confirmation message.

e.g. :

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <img/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <h:msg>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So I tried to add messages to the Faces Context based on 2 different client ids

```
<tr>
    <td height="5">
        <h:messages style="color:darkred" id="error_message" />
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td width="89%" class="InfoMsg" align="center">
        <h:messages id="confirm_message" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And the java layer:

```
FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage(Constants.saveMessageConfirm);

FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(Constants.STATIC_CONFIRM_MSG_CLIENT_ID, facesMessage);
```

---

But, even if I add messages to clientId confirm_message - and only to confirm_message - and not to error_message - The message is shown twice in 2 different styles (refer the HTML above).

2 Questions :

1. What is the problem here?
2. If I want to show the image inside a `td` in the second `tr` and conditionaly show that second `tr` when confirm messages are present - what is the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The `h:messages` displays **all** messages, also the ones which are already displayed in a `h:message` in the page. You can however set it to **only** display messages with a `null` client ID using `globalOnly="true"`.

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

You can also give the message a different style depending on the [`FacesMessage.Severity`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.Severity.html):

```
<h:messages infoClass="info" errorClass="error" />
```

with for example this CSS which hides the [`INFO`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html#SEVERITY_INFO) messages and makes [`ERROR`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html#SEVERITY_ERROR) messages red:

```
.info {
     display: none;
}
.error {
     color: red;
}
```

You can use `redisplay="false"` to tell it to not display the already displayed messages via e.e. `<h:message>`.

```
<h:messages redisplay="false" />
```

You only need to make sure it's placed in the component tree *after* all those other message components. You can if necessary make use of CSS to reposition it somewhere in top.

Just to be sure,

```
facesContext.addMessage("clientId",  facesMessage);
```

this will attach the given message to a `<h:message for="clientId">` not to a `<h:messages id="clientId">` as you seem to expect.

Comment: I posted a question concerning your first statement in this post. Can you take a look please? [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598549/icemessages-hmessages-showing-messages-which-are-already-displayed-in-a-comp).

Comment: @this: Sorry my statement was after all indeed wrong. Nobody is perfect :) Please update your question. I have updated this and other answer. Thank you for the wake up.

Comment: BlausC, you are amazing.  How did you know it only could have one child element?

Comment: @BalusC is this a good practice to use component's id in facelet and in backing bean as a simple string (like it is done in your last example)? Maybe there is a better way to synchronize this value? E.g. declare a constant, bind its value in the view and use the same constant in backing bean's code?

Comment: If you simply want to display messages in a specific style, you can use the `style` tag inline without css. Example: `<h:messages style="color: red"/>`

Comment: @jackz314: inline styles are considered bad practice in HTML.

Comment: I admit it's not easy to maintain inline CSS, but I think it's reasonable if used in a simple project. In my case, I only have to do this once for one form.

Answer (score 5):

change `<h:messages>` to `<h:message>`

`<h:messages` displays all messages for the current context, `<h:message>` displays a specific message.

and I believe you want to change `id` to `for` to give it a target, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

We can have different types of h:messages for different severity levels. For example you might want to display all the error messages in a red box and rest with different styles like yellow for warn and green for info. You can also wrap around with different panels. You can do so by having different h:messages and apply the styles individually.

```
<!--Displays only Error Messages-->
<h:messages styleClass="mystyle" layout="list" id="msg1" infoStyle="display:none"       warnStyle="display:none"></h:messages>

<!--Displays only Warning Messages-->
<h:messages styleClass="messages" layout="list" id="msg2" errorStyle="display:none"     infoStyle="display:none"></h:messages>

<!--Displays only Info Messages-->
<h:messages styleClass="messages" layout="list" id="msg2" errorStyle="display:none"     warnStyle="display:none"></h:messages>
```