# There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered

Tags: jsf, message

I have a JSF 2.1 + PrimeFaces 3.3 page:

```
<h:form id="particluar">
  <p:message id="msg" globalOnly="true" display="text"/>

  <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="test">
    <h:panelGrid id="panel2" columns="3">
      <p:inputText id="name1" value="Student.studentID" required="true"/>          
      <p:commandButton value="Check Name" actionListener="#{Student.abc}" process="name1" update="panel2" />
      <p:message id="msg1" for="name1" display="text"/>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:inputText id="name2" required="true"/>
    <p:message id="msg2" for="name2" display="text"/>

    <p:inputText id="name3" required="true"/>
    <p:message id="msg3" for="name3" display="text"/>

  </h:panelGrid>
  <p:commandButton value="submit" actionListener="#{Student.xyz}" update="particluar" />
</h:form>
```

I'm trying to manually add faces messages when the name is invalid:

```
public void xyz() {
  if (name1.equals("primefaces")) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msg1", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Invalid Name", "Invalid Name"));
  }
  if (name2.equals("primefaces")) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msg2", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Invalid Name", "Invalid Name"));
  }
  if (name3.equals("primefaces")) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msg3", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Invalid Name", "Invalid Name"));
  }
}
```

But they do not show up and the server log keeps printing the following warning:

> There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every
>   FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered

How do I show them in the page?

And, a second question, if I submit the form with three empty input fields, it shows "required input error message" in each `<p:message>` associated with the `<p:inputText>`. How do I show them in the `<p:message globalOnly="true">`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *How do I show them in the page?*

You need to specify a valid client ID. The client ID is not the same as component ID. The client ID is whatever you see in the JSF-generated HTML output. Also, the client ID should be the one of the input component, not of the message component.

So, given a

```
<h:form id="particular">
    <p:inputText id="name1" />
    <p:message id="msg1" for="name1" />
</h:form>
```

the input component has the client ID `particular:name1` (rightclick page in browser and do *View Source* to see it yourself). So, the message should be attached on exactly this client ID.

```
context.addMessage("particular:name1", message);
```

---

> *And, a second question, if I submit the form with three empty input fields, it shows "required input error message" in each `<p:message>` associated with the `<p:inputText>`. How do I show them in the `<p:message globalOnly="true">`?*

The `<p:message>` is not the valid component for that, you should use `<p:messages>`.

```
<p:messages id="msg" globalOnly="true" display="text"/>
```

The `globalOnly="true"` attribute means that only messages with a `null` client ID will be shown. So, you should just add exactly such a message.

```
context.addMessage(null, message);
```

#### See also:

- [How to use JSF h:messages better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930535/how-to-use-jsf-hmessages-better)
- [When and how is clientID generated in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351976/when-and-how-is-clientid-generated-in-jsf)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the non-global messages ("Invalid name") which you're trying to add there should actually be done by a fullworthy validator. See also [How to perform validation in JSF, how to create a custom validator in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047866/how-to-perform-validation-in-jsf-how-to-create-a-custom-validator-in-jsf/6047913#6047913) for a concrete example.

Comment: thanks, your answer make me clear and solved my problem.
But may I know how to count and show out the total number of error?
example, if this 3 inputText with required="true", and I empty the field, so now it will show out error message on each of message beside it, but how do I count and show the "total 3 error" in the global message? thanks..

Comment: Your best bet would be a `PhaseListener` which runs on `beforePhase` of `RENDER_RESPONSE`. You can get the messages by `FacesContext#getMessageXxx()` methods and count them and then add a new global message.