# When and how is clientID generated in JSF?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, page-lifecycle, clientid

In order to more understand the clientID generation in JSF (2.x), could someone explain to me when exactely does JSF generates the client ID (which lifecycle phase, build time or render time ...)?

And how the client ID will be generated (if providing /not providing component ID and not, randomly or using a specific logic...) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> *In order to more understand the clientID generation in JSF (2.x), could someone explain to me when exactely does JSF generates the client ID (which lifecycle phase, build time or render time ...)?*

It has to end up in HTML response. It's thus generated during render response. If you put a debug breakpoint on [`UIComponent#getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)) method, then you'll see further down in the stack that (in case of Mojarra) `RenderResponsePhase#execute()` has been invoked. This is sufficient hint about the current phase in the lifecycle when the breakpoint is hit.

> *And how the client ID will be generated (if providing /not providing component ID and not, randomly or using a specific logic...)?*

The concrete implementation of the abstract `UIComponent#getClientId()` method can be found in [`UIComponentBase#getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#getClientId(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)). [Its source code can be found at grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.0/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.java#UIComponentBase.getClientId%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29). How it will be generated is just described in [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)):

> `public abstract String getClientId(FacesContext context)`
>
> Return a client-side identifier for this component, generating one if necessary. The associated [`Renderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html), if any, will be asked to convert the clientId to a form suitable for transmission to the client.
>
> The return from this method must be the same value throughout the lifetime of the instance, unless the `id` property of the component is changed, or the component is placed in a [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) whose client ID changes (for example, [`UIData`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html)). However, even in these cases, consecutive calls to this method must always return the same value. The implementation must follow these steps in determining the clientId:
>
> Find the closest ancestor to this component in the view hierarchy that implements `NamingContainer`. Call `getContainerClientId()` on it and save the result as the `parentId` local variable. Call [`getId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getId()) on this component and save the result as the `myId` local variable. If `myId` is `null`, call [`context.getViewRoot().createUniqueId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#createUniqueId()) and assign the result to `myId`. If `parentId` is non-`null`, let `myId` equal `parentId +`[`UINamingContainer.getSeparatorChar(javax.faces.context.FacesContext)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html#getSeparatorChar(javax.faces.context.FacesContext))`+ myId`. Call [`Renderer.convertClientId(javax.faces.context.FacesContext, java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html#convertClientId(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String)), passing `myId`, and return the result.

Pretty clear, is it? The most important part is perhaps memorizing components which implement `NamingContainer` and thus prepend their client ID. In standard JSF 2.x, that are at least `<h:form>`, `<h:dataTable>`, `<ui:repeat>`, `<f:subview>` and `<cc:implementation>`. [If you gently give all components a fixed ID](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/viewhandlers/NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler), then you'll also see that pattern back in the generated HTML output.

If you don't give those components a fixed ID, then instead the JSF-generated ID will be used which can be obtained via [`UIViewRoot#createUniqueId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#createUniqueId()) (as already hinted in the above javadoc extract). [Its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#createUniqueId()) says:

> `public String createUniqueId()`
>
> Generate an identifier for a component. The identifier will be prefixed with [`UNIQUE_ID_PREFIX`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#UNIQUE_ID_PREFIX), and will be unique within the non-NamingContainer child sub-trees of this `UIViewRoot`.

That prefix is [`j_id`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/constant-values.html#javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.UNIQUE_ID_PREFIX). It isn't explicit on how the implementation should generate it, so all implementors are free to implement it. They usually use an incremented index of the component count in the tree. So, the first component, the `UIViewRoot`, could get an ID of `j_id1`. Its first child could get an ID of `j_id2`. Etcetera. You can track back the logic by putting a debug breakpoint on `UIViewRoot#createUniqueId()` method or even the [`UIComponentBase#setId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#setId(java.lang.String)) method.

#### See also:

- [How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/cannot-find-component-with-expression-foo-referenced-from-bar-fajax-con)
- [By default, JSF generates unusable ids, which are incompatible with css part of web standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10726653/by-default-jsf-generates-unusable-ids-which-are-incompatible-with-css-part-of/)
- [Avoiding duplicate ids when reusing facelets compositions in the same naming container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552654/avoiding-duplicate-ids-when-reusing-facelets-compositions-in-the-same-naming-con)

Comment: reading again your post, you said "putting a debug breakpoint on UIViewRoot#createUniqueId()", could i debug inside the JSF implementation when running my projects? i can't do it now as all the fils are '.class' and not '.java' (I am using tomcat)

Comment: You need to attach source files. How to do that depends on the IDE. In Eclipse there's usually a button which says "Attach source". Provide then the source JAR file in there. Or, use Maven, it'll automatically download the sources (and the remainder of the Internet).