# How update attribute of p:remoteCommand works

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Primefaces 6.0. I understand that update attribute of p:remoteCommand should be used to specify clientIds of the components that should be updated by AJAX. I am trying to understand how PF works. In combination with DataTable it doesn't seem to work as expected. When I try to directly set  `update="form:dataTable:2:bColumn"`, it has no efect. However, doing this (commented out in the below code) `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:dataTable:2:bColumn");` will force PF to update the specified outputText.

Why is this happening? I will be happy for technical explanation - I am trying to find the answer by debugging PF Java/Javascript sources.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:remoteCommand name="remoteCall"
                     action="#{grid4.onEdit}"
                     update="form:dataTable:2:bColumn"
    />

    <p:dataTable id="dataTable"
                 var="gridItem"
                 value="#{grid4.gridItems}"
                 editable="true" editMode="cell"
    >

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit"
                oncomplete="remoteCall()">
        </p:ajax>

        <p:column headerText="A">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{gridItem.a}" /></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{gridItem.a}"/></f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="B">
            <h:outputText id="bColumn" value="#{gridItem.b}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Grid4 {
    private List<GridItem> gridItems = new ArrayList<>();


    public Grid4() {
        gridItems.add(new GridItem("1", "a","b"));
        gridItems.add(new GridItem("2", "a","b"));
        gridItems.add(new GridItem("3", "a","b"));
    }

    public void onEdit() {
        System.out.println("onEdit()");
        gridItems.get(2).setB("CHANGED VALUE");
//        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:dataTable:2:bColumn");
    }

    public List<GridItem> getGridItems() {
        return gridItems;
    }

    public void setGridItems(List<GridItem> gridItems) {
        this.gridItems = gridItems;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically jsf ids an client side ids are two different things (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354617/5527433) answer and [this](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com.co/2009/02/jsf-working-with-component-ids.html)  post for a better understanding).

When you use `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:dataTable:2:bColumn");` that method use the client id to find the components that have to be updated, but in the case of the `update` property of `p:remoteCommand` it is expecting a jsf id, not the generated client id, so that´s why your update doesn't work. However, primefaces support [jquery selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080861/how-do-primefaces-selectors-as-in-update-myclass-work) to update components, so you could use a client side id on an `update` property like this `update="@(#yourElementId)"`

Comment: Had no idea about the jquery selectors. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by mentioning that this is not specific to the `p:remoteCommand`. The reason for the behaviour you notice is rather simple although not directly obvious maybe since it is unfortunately not in the PrimeFaces documentation.

The update attribute in:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remoteCall"
                 action="#{grid4.onEdit}"
                 update="form:dataTable:2:bColumn"
/>
```

uses a relative path if it does not start with a : and since the `p:remoteCommand` is already in the naming container with `id='form'`, the form in the update attribute is superfluous and even makes it not work (run your app in dev mode, add a messages tag and see the errors).

So

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remoteCall"
                 action="#{grid4.onEdit}"
                 update="dataTable:2:bColumn"
/>
```

Should work, as should

```
<p:remoteCommand name="remoteCall"
                 action="#{grid4.onEdit}"
                 update=":form:dataTable:2:bColumn"
/>
```

The

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:dataTable:2:bColumn");
```

is **always** absolute, so the colon is not needed here and it will find the element starting from the root (form 'prefix' is needed then)

Comment: Solutions you provided don't work. After more debugging I found out that remoteCommand is being wrongly translated into HTML. In the generated HTML I can see remoteCall = function() {PrimeFaces.ab({s:"form:j_idt4",f:"form",u:"form:dataTable:bColumn",pa:arguments[0]});} . Note that row number is missing. After debugging the source code of PF, it looks like a bug. The code is generating this 'clientId' by looking up the component (output text field) first. But after it finds it, there is some side effect that nullifies the clientId field.

Comment: That is a separte issue. The value of the update attribute in your question is wrong in the way I describe in my answer.