# <h:message for="foo"> does not seem to work on <section id="foo">

Tags: jsf, message

I have defined this:

```
   <ui:define name="content">
        <section id="documents">
....
            <h:message for="documents" errorClass="errorc" />
        </section>
```

This is inside a `<body><main>` tags in the upper template.

Then my controller does this:

```
} catch (MyException e) {
            ctx.addMessage("documents", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Trying to raise an error", null));
        }
```

But the error is not shown in the `h:message`. I assume I am using wrongly the target ID, but I don't know how to do it. I have tried to move the `h:message` outside the section but doesn't work either.

I could only make it work with [general h:messages with null client ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930535/how-to-use-jsf-hmessages-better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`<h:message>` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserver-faces-2-2/vdldocs-facelets/h/message.html) (emphasis mine):

> `for`
>
> Client identifier of the **component** for which to display messages.

The `<section>` tag is a plain HTML element, not a JSF component.

Use e.g. `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` component to let JSF generate a `<div>` element.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block id="documents">

    <h:message for="documents" ... />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Or create a custom component generating `<section>`.

Comment: I see, thanks. A custom component would be a JSF tag for example?