# How to add Faceslets message on different messages component?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I would like to have different messages on different message components, but unfortunately message always display on both message components.

TestFaces.java

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
@javax.inject.Named
public class TestFaces implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public String callMsg001() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msg001",
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "This is msg001", null));

        return null;
    }
    
    public String callMsg002() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("msg002",
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "This is msg002", null));

        return null;
    }

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Index</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        msg001: <h:messages id="msg001" style="msg001" />
        msg002: <h:messages id="msg002" style="msg002"/>
        <h:commandButton
            value="Trigger msg001"
            action="${testFaces.callMsg001()}">
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton
            value="Trigger msg002"
            action="${testFaces.callMsg002()}">
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Output
[image]

I would like to have different messages on different message components.

Comment: Try to read [this: `h:messages` vs `h:message`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930535/how-to-use-jsf-hmessages-better) and remember that a form without `prependId="false"` add a prefix to the component's id.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JSF h:messages better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930535/how-to-use-jsf-hmessages-better)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @WoAiNii

Working example as below.

TestFaces.java

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
@javax.inject.Named
public class TestFaces implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String callCmd001() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "This is global cmd001", null));
        
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("form001:cmd001",
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "This is cmd001", null));

        return null;
    }

    public String callCmd002() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "This is global cmd002", null));
        
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("form001:cmd002",
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "This is cmd002", null));

        return null;
    }

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Message Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form001">
        msgs: <h:messages/><br/>
        msgs global Only: <h:messages globalOnly="true"/><br/>
        msg001: <h:message for="form001:cmd001"/><br/>
        msg002: <h:message for="form001:cmd002"/><br/>
        <h:commandButton id="cmd001"
            value="call cmd001"
            action="${testFaces.callCmd001()}">
        </h:commandButton>
        <h:commandButton id="cmd002"
            value="call cmd002"
            action="${testFaces.callCmd002()}">
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```